# How can I get the frame ticks from DateListPlot?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

`DateListPlot` very nicely chooses major and minor frame tick and frame tick label/markers.

I am building a custom graphics function where either the `x` or `y` axis is time and I would like to use what`DateListPlot` provides. How can I do this without simply overlaying and using `Show`?

Comment: Looking at the `FullForm` of your `DateListPlot` might give you some ideas...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Options will do it:

```
data = {{{2006, 10, 1}, 10}, {{2006, 10, 15}, 12},
   {{2006, 10, 30}, 15}, {{2006, 11, 20}, 20}};
plot = DateListPlot[data];
Options[plot, FrameTicks]
```

For example, modifying the contents of FrameTicks:

```
data = {DateList[{2006, #, 1}], #} & /@ Range[40];
plot = DateListPlot[data];
ticks = FrameTicks /. Options[plot, FrameTicks];
ticks[[2, 1, All, 2]] = Style[#, Red] & /@ ticks[[2, 1, All, 2]];
pos = Position[plot, FrameTicks];
plot[[Sequence @@ Most[First@pos]]] = FrameTicks -> ticks;
plot
```

[image]

Comment: or `plot /. (FrameTicks -> _) -> (FrameTicks -> ticks)` to eliminate the 2nd and 3rd last lines.